# API not finding any function

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I am working on this project on asp.net web.api and I have some functions for CRUD operations.
Now where I'm stuck is that when I try to test my API at web.postman.com, it can not find my functions. All it does is returning Error 404-Not found.

This is just one of many functions of my AccountController:

```
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("api/account/GetByID/{id}")]
        public IHttpActionResult GetById(string id)
        {
        var result = sl3.Operator.Where(x => x.id == id).FirstOrDefault();
        if (id == null)
        {
        return NotFound();
        }
        else
        {
        return Ok(result);
        }
        }
```

When I try on my localhost/swagger (a nugget package that I have installed on this project for documentation of my API) it works perfectly, all functions, without any problem at all. So I don't know where is the catch here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, no one answered so I figured it out by myself.
I removed the `[Route("api/account/GetByID/{id}")]` and suddenly it works.
Now if someone sees this question and answer, I want to ask you that is it really secured or is it fine if I leave it without a declare route? Because of course by default it will take the **localhost/api/{controller}/{action}** route but my question is, will it be any problem if we do not declare it? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what could be the issue, but first thing first.

1. If your API is available locally then please try to use Postman desktop versions to perform test activity.
2. Or there could be an issue with your routing, please make sure, controller and method should not repeat 'api' keyword.
3. Else Please add more details like environment, controller, and annotations.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your time answering this. 1. I just tried all the process in the Postman desktop platform and the results were all the same.
2. I tried running it without he keyword 'api' too and still it could not find any function of my controller.
Please check the other answer that I did to this question. It is working now but I'm not so sure if I should live it routing by default or it is a must that we have to declare it's route. Since I'm just a beginner at Asp.net and Web Api's, could you lease tell me if this method of solving this is efficient enough or not. Thank you.